# MAUI 8 Android kill my application after initial install

Tags: android, maui

I'm creating MAUI 8 Application what should Receive FCM notifications. But the problem is that when I install the Application and start it and after that I close the Application and Remove it from the Tasks, the Application is killed(Force Stop is gray out), but when I Start it again and Stop it from the Tasks, the Application is running on background and I can Force Stop it. Any ideas why that happening only after install and first start?

Answer (score 0):

If someone face the same issue, this happens only when the app is deployed by Visual Studio. If the app is installed by apk file, everything is okay.

Comment: Excellent! You add more details to your post and check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.